# javascript nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested, push

Hi I want to use nested arrays in my javascript function but it doesn't work. Here is my function:

```
var arr = [];

function test(id, value){
   arr.push(new Array("id" = id, "value" = value));
}
```

so as you find out I want to create something like this:

```
arr[0][id = "example0", value = "value0"];
arr[1][id = "example1", value = "value1"];
arr[2][id = "example2", value = "value2"];
...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `new Array("id" = id, "value" = value)` is not an array.

You want an array holding an object.

```
arr.push({"id":id, "value":value});
```

Read values

```
console.log(arr[0].id);
```